# What exactly happens in a low and a high pass filter?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, signal-processing

I know the mathematics and equations behind the circuitry and how they tell us that the resistor blocks high frequency ac signals and allows low frequency ac signals to pass through with undiminished amplitude. Similarly, a capacitor blocks low frequency ac signals and allows high frequency ac signals to pass through with undiminished amplitude.

But what is the physics behind this? Can anyone explain to me this phenomenon without using any mathematics?

I did not find a proper theoretical explanation for this anywhere.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. You said you know the math and circuitry behind it, so the only thing left is to understand the physics behind how the components themselves operate, which is a Wikipedia page away...

Comment: The mathematical derivation for it should be entirely based on the circuit, which is physics.  If you understand how to get it with the math, just consider what you are actually doing.

Comment: The resistor isn't blocking anything.

Comment: @JonCuster, unless it has some parasitic inductance.

Comment: @JamalS  What is the physical interpretation behind the capacitor blocking the low frequency signals I know about its reactance but what is actually happening inside the capacitor that makes it block the low frequency signals but allowing the high frequency signals to pass?

Comment: @ThePhoton - having used a precision wire-round resistor as a 'precision' small value inductor before, I can agree to some extent...

Comment: @JonCuster it could be argued that the resistor is absolutely blocking something: if the capacitor (in the low pass configuration) has a low impedance (high frequency), then most of the voltage drops across the resistor, so it is, in a very real sense, "blocking" the signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a low pass circuit, the capacitor can absorb small amounts of charge without the voltage changing much. When you put a high frequency signal into the low pass filter, the capacitor acts as a short circuit - the small amount of charge that flows in one half cycle can be "absorbed" by the capacitor without the voltage changing significantly. When the frequency is lower, the capacitor has time to charge and the voltage changes - so the circuit "let's through" the input signal.

You can do a similar analysis for the high pass configuration - again ask yourself how the voltage across the capacitor changes with time.